# TFS Build - Not including latest changeset

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a custom TFS Build template that includes a procedure that runs a process that involves getting some data from a server and checking it into TFS before moving onto the main build process.

The steps are as follows:

1. Set build number
2. Run our custom script - get data, check into TFS
3. Initialize environment
4. Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control
5. Associate the changesets that occurred since the last good build
6. Compile, Test and Publish

The issue I appear to be having is that all change sets since the last successful build are included, except, the change set associated with the script run at step 2.

Does anyone know what could be going on here? my guess is that the logic that is looking for the change sets since last build is using a cut off that is set at the moment the build is requested (hence why the last change set is ignored) but this is just an uneducated guess.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why you want to use step2 to check in code before build starts, and what data you need to check in? The changeset created in steps seems can't be recognized using the default Associate changesets activity.

Comment: We have a server that contains default data that is inserted into the database at install time. The process in step two reads that data into an XML format and checks in the resulting files into TFS. This is normally kicked off manually but for our nightly builds we need this to be done as part of the build.

Comment: What's the build system you use? XAML or vNext?

Comment: I am using XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying the steps below:

1. Edit your build definition and go to "Process" tab.
2. Enter "T" under "Get version" option.
   [image]
3. Queue the build and check the result.

Comment: What does 'T' means?

Answer (score 0):

I would have two builds chained: the first build generates and check-in the files the second simply pulls them down.

Comment: We are using TFS 2017 CI pipeline for MVC project, also I added the project's bin files into the TFS, there is no problem with the pipeline, its getting succeeded and artifact is generated successfully but the main problem is that if I made any changes in code related to project's DLL,

the CI pipeline's build solution not generated its own latest bin file

until or unless I manually check Out the project.dll file and than check In the file than pipeline will pick the changes, what I am missing, same result by using 'MSBUILD' tasks, I also select clean the 'all directories' but no result v